# Authentication by certificate in ssh -- am I doing it properly?

Tags: linux, ssh, certificate

I've read various articles about how to setup authentication without password, only by certificate and I haven't a common solution: some suggest this, other that. How to do this properly?

This config works, yes, but maybe there's something I should I remove? Or something I should add anything else?

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

My question is about this config in particular and I don't need any more links to read.

Comment: The above denies password use and requires key-based authentication. Is there some additional goal you are looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You don't need `RSAAuthentication`. It is deprecated in current OpenSSH.
- `PermitEmptyPasswords` is not needed once you disable the password authentication.
- `UsePAM` should stay on in most of todays systems since it does not do only authentication, but also setting up your session.

Comment: `UsePAM` -- by on you mean "yes" or merely its presence with `no` as it is now?

Comment: "should stay on" ~~ "yes" (default is `no` on OpenBSD, but all Linuxes are using PAM if I am right).